# How would you split a PHP project and keep maintaining both?

Tags: php, git

I have a PHP website (A) that I need to split in two (creating B).

B would have most features in common with A, very few additions, and a lot of stuff in A would be useless for B, thus removed.

I'd like to create B but still maintain it, while maintaining A, possibily automatically.

We use Git.

Suggestions?

Comment: Have you looked into branching it?

Comment: @EM-Creations that's what I'd like to know more about. What would be a correct workflow?

Comment: Refactor the common functionality into a submodule?

Comment: This is a very wide field. I also would suggest branching B from A.
You can then cherry-pick or merge stuff from A to B when needed.

In most cases [this strategy](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) does a good job for me.

Comment: @fragmentedreality We already use git-flow. I'm not sure how to apply that to my needs.

Comment: You could branch B from A. Then you delete all the stuff from A that is unneeded in B. Add your changes that differ from A and commit to B.

After you have checked out A (probably you keep two 'working copies' of A and B in different directories to prevent switching branches all the time) you commit them to A and in your B you `--fetch all` pull the changes from A. Then you do a merge without commit and remove all the unneeded stuff from the staging and commit to B. Voilá, you got A's relevant changes in B.

I have to admit this is not much of automation. You probably could write a hook for it

Comment: @fragmentedreality, do you perhaps have some kind of example or a blog post documenting this?

Answer (score 0):

I frequently get into this situation, and I use 2 patterns at the same time to fix it.

First off, since branch "A" will have fewer things unwanted in branch "B" than vice versa, I would recommend making sure that in "A", any bit of code you add which you don't want part of B's functionality, you should encapsulate with `if` statements, that always pass in the case of branch "A", you merge that into branch "B", but in branch "B", you set the variable you defined in branch "A" to the opposite value. If you haven't done so already, do it now and find all the bits of code you don't want in branch "B" and encapsulate them in an `if`. Don't forget that if a piece of functionality you added required you to remove a previous functionality of branch "B", then find the old bit of code and that to the `else` block.

From hereon, every change that you make that would be common with both branches should go to branch "A", and to apply it for branch "B", you go to branch "B" and merge with "A". If you keep doing that, you'll always keep the changes made in branch "A", branch "A" will never take the changes from branch "B" (keeping it separate), and if you follow what I said in the previous paragraph, the "bad changes" of branch A won't have any effect on branch "B" since the `if` statements will yield false and the branch "A" bits of code won't run.

The second pattern is that in case you start making common features to both branches, but on branch B as you are not supposed to but may be doing anyway either because it's more easily testable on branch B or because you simply forgot to switch to branch A before making the changes, then that's fine too. In that case, all the commits you made on branch "B" that you need on branch "A" as well should be cherry-picked from branch "A". Meaning if you make commits commit1, commit2 and commit3 on branch "B", but you need then on "A" as well, then you checkout to branch "B" and do:

```
git cherry-pick commit1 commit2 commit3
```

And with that you take the changes you made on branch "B" that you needed on branch "A" as well, plus you don't screw up your pattern such that on branch "B", merging with branch "A" will not give you unwanted changes.

Comment: Sorry about the previous empty comment... I'd like more details about this setup. I have an e-commerce website (A) with multi-store, multi-language, etc., now I'd like to create a new e-commerce website (B) without those functionalities (but probably some other features in the long run). How would it work if I then fix a bug on A that I need to fix on B, too? Or worse: if I commit to the cart code in A and I don't need it in B, how do I exclude that from being pulled in? Thank you

Comment: That actually sounds more like the 2 projects have a common ancestor rather than one being the simple extension of the other.

In that case, and if you haven't started branch B yet, I would suggest making any further commits that would be common to both projects on a new branch core that starts off at where branch A is. Any new additions that are unique to branch A or B should be committed on that branch only.

If you need to update your branch `A` or `B` with the changes made that are to be common to both branches (branch `core`), you simply merge on `A` or `B` with `core`.

Comment: And you should never be on `core` to merge with any changes you make on `A` or `B`, because they will contain changes that are unique to their own projects.

If you accidentally commit changes on `A` or `B` which you actually intended to be part of the core, then from `core` do `git cherry-pick` with the needed commits accidentally made on `A` or `B`.
Is there anything that isn't clear?

Comment: it is clear enough in teory, I'll try to put it into practice. Thank you very much.